# Not able to install anything in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I am not able to use apt-get to install anything in Ubuntu. Below is the error I get when I run sudo apt-get install :

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get -f install`
Also tried re-configuring dpkg: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
And also: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.
All produce the same error. Would appreciate any help / suggestions on this.

Comment: When did this start happening? i.e., what's the last thing you did to the system before it started happening?

Comment: Please check `ls /var/cache/apt/archives apt-listchanges*` to see if there is a .deb package present for list-changes

Comment: I can not tell exactly what triggered this issue. Bumped into it only today.

Comment: @CharlesGreen you mean I should do something like this: `ls /var/cache/apt/archives | grep apt-listchanges*`

Comment: Yes - the apt-listchanges package is apparently having issues of some kind - it is not installed by default, but if the deb file is presetn perhaps it could be reinstalled.  Alternatively, it could be removed  with `sudo apt purge apt-listpackages`

Comment: The .deb file in not present. What I meant is: `ls /var/cache/apt/archives | grep apt-listchanges*` returns empty

Comment: I'm going to guess that there is also no file `/usr/bin/apt-listchanges` as mentioned in the first line of your error message.  I think your choices would be either to download and install the package manually, or attempt to purge it as I mentioned above.

Comment: Strange thins is, the file `/usr/bin/apt-listchanges ` is present, however. That was the first thing I looked for after getting the error.

Comment: Perhaps you need to make the file executable? Or, perhaps the system can't figure out how to execute it. Is it a text file? Does it have a proper bang at the beginning (eg `#!/bin/sh`)? Is it a binary file? Perhaps you've got an incompatible version installed (eg. a 64-bit version on a 32-bit system)?

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem and found this page while troubleshooting. The error message is `/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found` but `/usr/bin/apt-listchanges` is actually still there. I noticed that it starts with `#!/usr/bin/python3` interpreter, which wasn't present in my system (mine was at `/usr/local/bin/python3`). I ran `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3` and it worked. NB: Change 3.7 as appropriate.

Comment: In my case incomplete python3.5 to 3.7 upgrade left a faulty link to python3

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the executable `apt-listchanges` has gone AWOL on your system.  Either of the two following suggestions should help your situation:

Remove the package:

`sudo apt purge apt-listchanges`

Second possible solution:  Download an reinstall the package.

- Download the package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt-listchanges
- install the package from your download directory with `sudo dpkg -i apt-listchanges*.deb`

Using this second method may prove problematic if some dependancy has also been removed.

Comment: A simple `apt-get -f --reinstall apt-listchanges` should be enough unless Apt breaks before it unpacks (re-)installed packages. In the latter case `apt-get download` or a manual download followed by `dpkg -i` are in order as you state. Neither case should require the removal of `apt-listchanges`; in fact I believe that the removal will cause further issues since Apt itself depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved if you follow the steps below:

- Remove apt-listchanges, then download apt-listchanges in another folder.
- Open your downloaded file and navigate to apt-listchanges as follows;

  `usr > bin > apt-listchanges`... that is in the folder usr/bin/
- Use the terminal to replace apt-listchange into the place usr/bin/ folder in your system *(the old one you deleted)*.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Python3 installation is broken.

Try running `python3`, see if it works.

If `python3` doesn't work but `/usr/bin/python3` works, you have a broken PATH.

If neither works:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges
sudo apt reinstall python3-minimal apt-listchanges
```